Access Denied on Cloudfront signed URL for a private S3 bucket
I am getting Access Denied 403 when trying to access a signed Cloudfront URL to an S3 bucket. The bucket is private and has blocked all public access, and I also have an OAC defined that grants permissions to CF to the S3 bucket.
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "cloudfront.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket_name>/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:SourceArn": "arn:aws:cloudfront::<id>:distribution/<id>"
                }
            }
        }
    ] }

I'm signing these URLs using the Python SDK
def get_rsa_signer(cls, message):
   kms_client = boto3.client("kms")
   response = kms_client.sign(
   KeyId=secrets_manager.get_env("CLOUDFRONT_KMS_PRIVATE_KEY_ID"),
   Message=message,
   MessageType="RAW",
   SigningAlgorithm="RSASSA_PKCS1_V1_5_SHA_256",
        )
  return response["Signature"]
 
cloudfront_signer = CloudFrontSigner( secrets_manager.get_env("CLOUDFRONT_PUBLIC_KEY_ID"),MediaStorage.get_rsa_signer)
url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(f"{settings.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN}/{file_key}",
date_less_than=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=7),
    )

These are the settings on the OAC
resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control" "cloudfront_backend_bucket" {
 name                    = "${var.environment}-cloudfront_backend_bucket"
 description             = "OAC for S3 bucket access"
 signing_behavior        = "always"
 signing_protocol        = "sigv4"
 origin_access_control_origin_type = "s3"
}

The public key ID on the URL is correct but I have no way of verifying whether the signature is correct, though I think the error in this case should be different.

Are the objects in the bucket encrypted by KMS? Also check this repost article.

It seems that the only problem is that I wasn't URL encoding the url that was to be signed.
The solution was:
url = cloudfront_signer.generate_presigned_url(f"{settings.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN}/{urllib.parse.quote(file_key)}",
date_less_than=timezone.now() + timedelta(days=7),
    )

